# Open url in new tab based on data in service in Kendo Menu

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, url-routing, kendo-menu

I searched around number of posts, but haven't any solution applicable to my scenario. I am population kendo-menu dynamically using an array build via sql.

```
<kendo-menu [items]="items"
            [vertical]="true"
            style="display:inline-block;">
</kendo-menu>
```

This is the sample I am following:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/menus/menu/vertical/

Here is how items array is structured:

```
export const items: any[] = [
  {
  text: 'Reportingd',
    items: [{ text: 'Dash', url: "https://www.google.com" },  {
    text: 'Realtime',
      items: [{ text: 'DesktopNew', url: "https://www.telerik.com" }, { text: 'laptop', url: "https://www.msn.com" }]
  }]
},
{
  text: 'Other Reporting',
  items: [{ text: 'Training', url: "https://www.msn.com" }, { text: 'UserManual', url: "https://www.msn.com" }, { text: 'Guide',
    items: }]
},
{
  text: 'Tools',
  items:[{ text: 'Training', url: "https://www.msn.com" }]
}];
```

However, this on click of menu/sub-menu opens url in the same window. I want to open in different window or new tab. HTML `<a>` tag does not work here. Please suggest

```
<a href="https://www.thesitewizard.com/" target="_blank">thesitewizard.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write select event for kendo menu something like below.

```
<kendo-menu [items]="items" (select)="onSelect($event)"></kendo-menu>
```

After that in onSelect method use window.open method like below.

```
public onSelect({ item }): void {
        if (!item.items) {
            window.open([item.url], "_blank");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am getting error on line window.open.....TS2345 (TS) Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Comment: Please upload/link workable code to debug.But the idea is same. @SilverFish

Comment: this code window.open(item.url.toString(), '_blank');  does open in new window for url, but also current application url to to the same url. So two windows with same url. for eg two windows for https://www.google.com will open

Comment: Please include http @SilverFish

Comment: Please accept the answer if you found it helped to solve your problem. @SilverFish

Comment: @ManirajSS, I am also facing the same problem. If you get this notification, please let me know how you solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the working example of opening selected menu item on a different tab using `kendo-menu` and `kendoMenuItemTemplate`

At first created the json file in `files.ts`. Next in the html, bring the reference and using `ng-template` and `kendoMenuItemTemplate`, we can loop through all the menu items. We can put all the normal html tags there to make it customizable. Below is the working example of the same.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrvbsm-5lk9uq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Ffiles.ts

Answer (score -1):

was able to resolve. It is 2 step process though. with following array structure given in initial post just open in current window. Therefore, fetched unique MenuID instead of url on initial load. Then as  ManirajSS suggested

```
public onSelect({ item }): void {

//call service to get url for this MenuID

}
```

Comment: Please give us the proper implementation, so that we can also solve the problem